# How to write a trigger when you update an account , set its BillingCountry as a concatenation of all its related Contact's mailingCountry?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, before-trigger, accountcontactrelation

I wrote the following code but I am unsure of my solution

```
trigger myTrigger on Account(before update){

Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
for(Account a : Trigger.new){

accMap.put(a.id,a)


}
List<String> countries = new List<String>();
List<Contact> relatedContacts = [Select Id, MailingCountry from Contact where AccountId IN : accMap.keyset()];

for(Contact con : relatedContacts){

countries.add(con.MailingCountry);

}

for(Account a : Trigger.new){

a.BillingCountry = String.join(relatedContacts, ',');


}


}
```

Is this the right approach? If not, what is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your trigger is close - you need to reinitialize the list of countries for each Account as the trigger will be invoked for 1-200 Accounts.

I took the liberty of rewriting it with better variable names and exploiting a map which relates the list of countries by accountId. I also used as Set to avoid duplicate country names

```
trigger myTrigger on Account(before update){

  Map<Id,Set[]> mailingCountriesByAccountId = new Map<Id,Set[]>();
  for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, MailingCountry FROM Contact
                   WHERE AccountId IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND
                         MailingCountry != NULL
                   ORDER BY AccountId] (
     if (!mailingCountriesByAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
         mailingCountriesByAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new Set<String>());
     }         
     mailingCountriesByAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c.MailingCountry);  
  }

  // now update trigger.new with concatenated countries
  for (Account a: Trigger.new) {
    a.BillingCountry = String.join(
                        new List<String>(mailingCountriesByAccountId.get(a.Id)),
                        ',');
  }

}
```

*Exercise left for the reader*

You will need to deal with field overflow as `BillingCountry` is a fixed length field and if too many child Contacts have different `MailingCountries`, you'll get a runtime exception

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also I had one question, the part where you said we need to reinitialize the list(or set) of countries each time for every account, does the following line take care of the same?  mailingCountriesByAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new Set<String>());

Comment: yes, you are correct, the map of accountId => set<string> is initialized for each new accountId encountered